# Limit select option with another select with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My object from database is coming like this:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 8,
        "concessionaria": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "asda"
        },
        "plano": {
            "id": 1,
            "sigla": "B3",
            "nome": "tetes"
        },
        "descricao": "45987",
        "enable": true
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "concessionaria": {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "teste2"
        },
        "plano": {
            "id": 3,
            "sigla": "b4",
            "nome": "Teste 2"
        },
        "descricao": "qweqwe",
        "enable": true
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "concessionaria": {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "teste2",
            "estado": "ES"
        },
        "plano": {
            "id": 2,
            "sigla": "B3",
            "nome": "Consumidores"
        },
        "descricao": "werwerw",
        "enable": true
    }
]
```

And i need to show two select, to choose the "concessionaria" and then the "planos" it has.

How can i do it since the "concessionaria" comes multiple times as the "plano" changes?

Comment: i can't get you question.. do you want to make selection of `concessionaria` and `planos` and show each one in a `select option`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create new model.

This sample show to you how can convert or create new model to get the `concessionaria` and `plano` as `array` to make them as `select option`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", [
  "$scope",
  function($scope) {

    var json = [{
        "id": 8,
        "concessionaria": {
          "id": 1,
          "nome": "asda"
        },
        "plano": {
          "id": 1,
          "sigla": "B3",
          "nome": "tetes"
        },
        "descricao": "45987",
        "enable": true
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "concessionaria": {
          "id": 2,
          "nome": "teste2"
        },
        "plano": {
          "id": 3,
          "sigla": "b4",
          "nome": "Teste 2"
        },
        "descricao": "qweqwe",
        "enable": true
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "concessionaria": {
          "id": 2,
          "nome": "teste2",
          "estado": "ES"
        },
        "plano": {
          "id": 2,
          "sigla": "B3",
          "nome": "Consumidores"
        },
        "descricao": "werwerw",
        "enable": true
      }
    ];

    $scope.model = {
      concessionaria: [],
      plano: []
    };

    angular.forEach(json, function(item) {
      var concessionaria = item.concessionaria;
      var plano = item.plano;
      $scope.model.concessionaria.push(concessionaria);
      $scope.model.plano.push(plano);
    });

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>concessionaria</label>
  <select ng-model="form.concessionaria" ng-options="item as item.nome for item in model.concessionaria"></select> {{form.concessionaria}}
  <hr />

  <label>plano</label>
  <select ng-model="form.plano" ng-options="item as item.nome for item in model.plano"></select> {{form.plano}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **limitTo** filter.

For example: `ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo 2"`

For more informations:  https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_limitto.asp

Answer (score 0):

You will need two selects, populate the first select with distinct values of concessionaria, and once user select a value from the first select you will have the id of concessionaria, then depending on that value you can populate the second select box with different plano. So if user selects a  concessionaria with id 2 your second select box will be populated with two plano (one with plano id 2 and other with plano id 3)